# Plotting a map (with background) starting from CSV long lat data in R

Tags: r, csv, sf

I have a csv file geolocalised in a simple way with latitude and longitude data for each row. I want to create a simple map with it.
But I am missing a step: how do I visualise my data on a map backgroup? For the moment I only manage to plot them in the void. I would like to obtain a static map with the package `mapsf`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(mapsf)
covid19 <- read_delim("https://public.opendatasoft.com/api/explore/v2.1/catalog/datasets/covid19-france-livraison-vaccin-region/exports/csv", delim = ";", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE) %>% 
      filter(iso3_code == "FXX") %>% 
      separate(centroid, c("lat", "long"), sep = ",", convert = T) %>% 
      st_as_sf(coords = c("lat","long"), crs=4269)
    
mf_map(covid19)
```

Comment: This looks like you've used the `mapsf` package function `mf_map` - it helps if you tell us which packages you've used.

Comment: Do you want a web-based map (which you can do with the `mapview` package) or a static image in an R graphics window?

Comment: Thanks @Spacedman, I have edited the question accordingly to your suggestions

Comment: Include all the libraries that generate your code and make the question clear. Do you want a "simple map"? If so, that's not much effort and the documentation shows you how to do that and more: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mapsf/vignettes/mapsf.html  If you want more, keep in mind, this site is not for providing tutorials, you should show what you tried and what went wrong. As the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) says, "actual problems".

Comment: Dear John Polo, I explained my problem and provided libraries and data. With my code, there is no background map. Can you solve it? Otherwise consider answering other questions